# Problema al añadir evento a varios elementos con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código PHP:

```
<?php
 $id_curso = base64_decode($_GET["var"]);

 $curso = new Curso($id_curso);

 $sesiones = $curso->getSesionesCurso();

 if(is_array($sesiones))
 {
    foreach($sesiones as $sesion)
    {
?>
      <h4 style="display: inline-block;"><?php echo $sesion["nombre"]; ?></h4>
      <a href="editar.php?var=<?php echo base64_encode($sesion["id_sesion"]); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
      <a id="eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 5px;" data-id="<?php echo $sesion["id_sesion"]; ?>">Eliminar</a>
      <hr>
<?php
    }
 }
?>
```

Y tengo este código JQuery:

```
$("#eliminar").on("click", function(){
  var id_sesion = $(this).attr("data-id");
  alert(id_sesion);
  return false; 
});
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que genero una consulta y la imprimo, por cada iteración se repiten los enlaces y el titulo h4 pero con diferentes valores, a un enlace le agregue un id y a ese enlace con jquery le agrego el evento click.

Lo que pretendo es que cuando se pulse sobre cualquier enlace de eliminar obtenga el valor guardado en el atributo `data-id`.

La pregunta es porque solo agrega el evento a la primera iteración y a las demás no??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el id del elemento a una clase en general al botón eliminar.

Cuando repites el id de un elemento, jQuery toma por defecto el primero, para hacer este cambio deberías cambiar en tu php:

```php
<a id="eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 5px;" data-id="<?php echo $sesion["id_sesion"]; ?>">Eliminar</a>
```

nuevo código php

```
<a class="btn btn-danger eliminar" style="margin-right: 5px;" data-id="<?php echo $sesion["id_sesion"]; ?>">Eliminar</a>
```

también en el código javascript deberás cambiar el **#** por un punto `.` para representar las clases .

```
$(".eliminar").on("click"..
```

Comment: Si es cierto, se me la onda y no se porque estaba manejando id en lugar de una clase